# Is the Android DownloadManager thread safe?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Is it safe to start downloads and delete downloads from separate threads or do you need to synchronize access to the DownloadManager?

Comment: As far as I know, the DownloadManager is thread safe and process safe since it is a system service. System services all run in their own processes and act like system-wide singletons.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't specify thread safety in the docs or in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java). Reading through the source, it seems to delegate all work to a ContentResolver.

The docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) suggest that ContentResolvers are thread safe.

> Similarly, a content provider can receive data requests that originate
>   in other processes. Although the ContentResolver and ContentProvider
>   classes hide the details of how the interprocess communication is
>   managed, ContentProvider methods that respond to those requests—the
>   methods query(), insert(), delete(), update(), and getType()—are
>   called from a pool of threads in the content provider's process, not
>   the UI thread for the process. Because these methods might be called
>   from any number of threads at the same time, they too must be
>   implemented to be thread-safe.